# WPF: Control that never causes children to NOT consume all available space

Tags: wpf, size, children, stackpanel, dockpanel

Right now I have a problem with `StackPanel`s inside `DockPanel`s. Often the `StackPanel` is taller than necessary for the contents, so the contents are stretched.

Is there something I can place in or around the `StackPanel` to mean "don't cause children to consume all avaialble space".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK the contents of the `StackPanel` do not "stretch" to fill it, anymore than any other control. i.e. the stretch to fill will be controlled by the `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` of the child elements.

The default is usually `Stretch`. Try setting it to `Left` etc.

Comment: I don't think the stretching is caused by the stack panel itself, but by whatever the stack panel is in.

Comment: Whatever the stackpanel is in, should not affect the stackpanels children. I tried a sample with a stackpanel in a dock panel as you state and it works fine - I can choose to stretch or not stretch the children of the stackpanel. Can you post a code sample?

Comment: Thanks. Your answer didn't make sense before, but now that I know more about WPF I see that you were correct.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what do you want your `StackPanel` to do?  If you want it to only consume the visible space, use a grid.  If you want to scroll the contents of your `StackPanel`, I believe you can put it in a [ScrollViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750665.aspx).

Comment: I'm fine with the stack panel consuming all the space itself. What I don't like is the button inside the stack panel also consuming all the space.

Comment: I think Schneider might know what's going on.